# how to stream internet radio on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Any one know how I can stream internet radio on iPhone with code?
Is a provider required?

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a programming question to me.

Comment: Don't vote down a question just because you don't understand it; that's rude.

Comment: Hi, did you get this working? I am also planning to implement internet video. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 13):

Matt Gallagher wrote a very good class for playing streaming audio on the Mac desktop and on the iPhone. See it here [How To Stream Internet Radio on iPhone](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html).

The flipside is you need a server running Nicecast, Shoutcast, Icecast or some other MP3 or AAC streaming audio software. And of course this server will need an audio connection to the radio station - either through an FM receiver, analog connection or dedicated hardware - entirely based upon the capabilities and infrastructure of the station.

Answer (score 6):

iPhone OS 3.0 supports live streaming via HTTP of MPEG-2 transport streams containing AAC audio (HE-AAC or AAC-LC). You'll find everything you need to know in the [HTTP Live Streaming Overview](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/iPhoneStreamingMediaOverview/iPhoneStreamingMediaOverview.html).

Answer (score 6):

yes you can play online streaming radio on your iPhone, use MPMoviePlayerController to stream your music

first you should import media player framework and audio toolbox framework

then 
import

```
 #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:    [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"]];
    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    player.view.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
```

you can stop playing music by just calling

```
[player stop];
```

thank you,

Comment: I tried this but it stops after 3 seconds and I have to click the play button again. Is there a setting that I should do for the `player` object to let it play continuously?

Comment: I solved this by initializing an instance-variable rather than just using the code above.

Comment: @antf MPMoviePlayerController will stream continuously , i think u have tried some opensources ! just put the code in the did load and it will work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **AVPlayer** class from the **AVFoundation** framework for playing streaming audio from a server. AVPlayer will only play codecs supported by the iOS SDK like mp3 and aac.

Some radio stations use the Microsoft streaming server which uses the mms:// protocol and the wma audio codec which is not supported by the iOS SDK. If you want to play these radio stations you must use a third party library like **libmms** or **FFmpeg**. The third party libraries will take care of the mms:// protocol and wma codec but you'll still need to use the **Audio Queue** services for playing the decoded audio data.